# Syncing Android devices without Google Cloud

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I develop a private Android app for a few users. It should sync data between the devices. I read about Sync Adapter implementations [like this one](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter) but the descriptions never mention the server side.

I think I need a Google Could account and pay a fair amount of money every month to run a VM that manages the server side of my sync mechanism, right?

Is there another way to just easily sync manually without any account? But then I guess I have to implement that from scratch by myself or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If thats for small number of users then http://parse.com/ should suit your needs. Its free if used by small number of users.